# Can I see the precise reason why LibreOffice thinks an .xlsx file is corrupt?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, error-logging

I've created a file using NPOI which Microsoft Excel can open, but which LibreOffice says is corrupt. It doesn't however give any kind of detailed explanation.

Is there a way to get more information about why it is having trouble opening the file? Is there a debug mode, or does it write to a log file?

Comment: Have you tried resaving the file from Excel and doing a compare with the one from NPOI?